# Tracking User Activity for badges

Tags: list, user-profile, web-analytics, user, information-management

I'm creating a QA site similar to Stack Overflow on SharePoint.

I'd like to be able to integrate some badges into the System.

I've thought of a few ideas, but I'd love some divergent thinking on tracking things like:

> How many comments has a user made?
>
> How many days in a row has a user visited?
>
> How many Questions has a user edited?
>
> How many sections of the FAQ has a user read?

Also:

Are badge requirements stored in code by necessity? Could there be a badges list with programmatic requirements? I.E. Single line of text column with predictable short hand like:

```
BadgeTitle = "Regular Visitor"; 
BadgeRequirement = "vs:(30)";
```

meaning, visited site 30 days in a row.

This is going in a Site Definition, so for our purposes there is no direct SQL access or Config Access.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm looking to do the very same thing; cook up a 'points' system for user activity.

Comment: I did, but ended up putting it on hold for a bit. It involves a lot of event listeners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started prototyping a similar solution.  I had a centralized list that stored the point values for each type of action and then put event receivers on specified lists that calculated the points.  The points can either be logged to SQL or another SharePoint list.

If you want to do something based on visits versus an actual update you would need another custom control added to your masterpage.  This is a bit trickier since it would need to be done smartly as to not impact performance.  Ideally you would not want to check to see if they visited today each and every time they request a page.

Comment: Agreed. List and thread performance make this a particular puzzle on SharePoint.